# Golang: How to declare returned variables WITH TYPE?

Tags: go

In GO, how do I declare the returned variables of a function WITH TYPE ?

e.g. I have this code

```
dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/dat")
check(err)
fmt.Print(string(dat))
```

but what I want is this:

```
var dat []byte, err error := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/dat")
check(err)
fmt.Print(string(dat))
```

However, no matter how I try, I only get this output

> syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting semicolon or newline or }

I'm working without IDE, and as the number of variables increases, it's really idiotic to have to keep all the return values's types in short-term memory... let alone if somebody else has to read the code.

How can I declare the returned tuple WITH type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using `:=` in your assignment there and that is a convenience syntax to declare and assign. It makes it so you don't have to provide the type, I assume the compiler just implies it by what is returned/whatever types come from the right hand side. Instead you need to do this;

```
var dat []byte
var err error

dat, err = ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/dat")
```

But no one does this because `dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/tmp/dat")` is such a cleaner syntax.

Comment: That indeed explains why nobody does it. Cleaner syntax would declare the types, however. This is merely less verbose syntax, which achieves its goal by hiding relevant, non-redundant information, which is not the same IMHO.

Comment: @StefanSteiger yeah that's true. That last comment is entirely subjective. It's what's most common in Go though. I agree that it can be annoying because you have to look at docs/go to implementation to see what types are being assigned. I prefer slightly more verbose syntax though I don't know if it would work well with Go's multiple return types. In say C# I am strongly against declaring with `var` instead of providing the type on the LHS.

Comment: So true for C#. For example in a codereview, you'd see immediately when you have IDatareader something = GetSomething(), but when you only have var something =  GetSomething(), you'll never notice it lacks a dispose or using.